# Oracle APEX - Store login value into session

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I want to store data into the session from the login page (9999 - login page). When I log in and check the session, the items are there, but with no values.

I tried to set the Source/Maintain session state/Per session (disk) option. Then I tried with pl/sql script but none of them working.

[image]

These settings working in any other pages but on the login page it doesn't work.

What can I do? Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always find username by addressing `:APP_USER`.

I have no idea what `P9999_NEW` is supposed to mean nor contain.